# Getting data from current week in BigQuery

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

i want to get the data from the current week, i tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `grouponi_groupon.tb_orders_items`
Where cast(creation_ts as date) between DATE_TRUNC(cast(creation_ts as date), WEEK) and current_date()
and item_id = 1067222
```

but I still get wrong dates. Also I want that the first day of the week will be Sunday and not Monday. Whats wrong with my query and how do I change the 1st day of the week to Sunday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should work if you replace `DATE_TRUNC(cast(creation_ts as date), WEEK)` by `DATE_TRUNC(current_date(), WEEK)`.
Also, when using the keyword `WEEK` in bigquery you have a week starting on Sunday, as said  [in Google Doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_trunc)

Comment: I feel so dumb haha. Thank you!

Comment: It happens to all of us, no worries ;). Please accept the answer if it answered your question.